# Merging two data frames, both with coordinates based on the closest location

Tags: r, dataframe

I have one large dataframe (~130000 rows) containing local variables and an other large dataframe (~7000 rows) containing the density of a species. Both have x and y coordinates but these coordinates don't always match. e.g:

```
df1 <- data.frame(X = c(2,4,1,2,5), Y = c(6,7,8,9,8), V1 = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), V2 = c("G", "H", "I", "J", "K"))
```

And:

```
df2 <- data.frame(X = c(2,4,6), Y = c(5,9,7), Dens = c(12, 17, 10))
```

I would like to add a column to df1 containing the density (Dens) from df2 if there is a point reasonably close-by. If there is no point close-by I would like it to show up as a NA. e.g:

```
X Y   V1   V2    Dens
2 6   A    G      12
4 7   B    H      NA     
1 8   C    I      17
2 9   D    J      NA
5 8   E    K      10
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, let's write a function to find the closest point in df2 for a single line of df1. Here I'm using simple cartesian distance (ie `(x1 - x2)^2 + (y1 - y2)^2`). If you have lat/lon you might want to change it to a better formula:

```
mydist <- function(row){
  dists <- (row[["X"]] - df2$X)^2 + (row[["Y"]]- df2$Y)^2
  return(cbind(df2[which.min(dists),], distance = min(dists)))
}
```

Once you have this, you just need to `lapply` it to each row, and add it to your first data:

```
z <- cbind(df1, do.call(rbind, lapply(1:nrow(df1), function(x) mydist(df1[x,]))))
```

For your test data, the output looks like:

```
   X Y V1 V2 X Y Dens distance
1  2 6  A  G 2 5   12        1
2  4 7  B  H 4 9   17        4
3  1 8  C  I 2 5   12       10
21 2 9  D  J 4 9   17        4
22 5 8  E  K 4 9   17        2
```

You can then do something like this to filter out those over your threshold:

```
threshold <- 5
z$Dens[z$distance > threshold] <- NA

   X Y V1 V2 X Y Dens distance
1  2 6  A  G 2 5   12        1
2  4 7  B  H 4 9   17        4
3  1 8  C  I 2 5   NA       10
21 2 9  D  J 4 9   17        4
22 5 8  E  K 4 9   17        2
```

Your actual data is very large (a simulated data set of the same size takes about 10 minutes on my computer). If possible you should `merge`, then only run this on those those are not exact matches (see `dplyr::anti_join`).