# Merge by lat/lon in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, spatial

My question is similar to [Merging two data frames, both with coordinates based on the closest location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34242154/merging-two-data-frames-both-with-coordinates-based-on-the-closest-location). I would like to merge two dataframes in R by latitude and longitude:

```
Dataframe 1
structure(list(lat = c(54L, 55L, 51L, 54L, 53L, 50L, 47L, 51L, 
49L, 54L), lon = c(14L, 8L, 15L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 13L, 5L, 13L, 11L
), PPP2000_40 = c(4606, 6575, 6593, 7431, 9393, 10773, 11716, 
12226, 13544, 14526)), .Names = c("lat", "lon", "PPP2000_40"), row.names =c(6764L, 8796L, 8901L, 9611L, 11649L, 12819L, 13763L, 14389L, 15641L, 
16571L), class = "data.frame")

# Dataframe 2
structure(list(lat = c(47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 48, 48, 48, 48
), lon = c(7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 7, 8, 9, 10), GDP = c(19.09982, 
13.31977, 14.95925, 6.8575635, 23.334565, 6.485748, 24.01197, 14.30393075, 21.33759675, 9.71803675)), .Names = c("lat", "lon", "GDP"), row.names = c(NA,  10L), class = "data.frame")
```

How can I merge them in R? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31668415/3526832):

```
library(geosphere)
mat <- distm(df1[,c('lon','lat')], df2[,c('lon','lat')], fun=distVincentyEllipsoid)
df1$GDP <- df2$GDP[apply(mat, 1, which.min)]
```

the result is then:

```
> df1
      lat lon PPP2000_40       GDP
6764   54  14       4606  9.718037
8796   55   8       6575 14.303931
8901   51  15       6593  9.718037
9611   54   7       7431 24.011970
11649  53   6       9393 24.011970
12819  50   5      10773 24.011970
13763  47  13      11716  6.485748
14389  51   5      12226 24.011970
15641  49  13      13544  6.485748
16571  54  11      14526  9.718037
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I will read up on the library and the function but could you kindly provide a little more information about

Comment: Thank you so much. I will read up on the library and the function but could you kindly provide a little more information about this part please?

`df1$GDP <- df2$GDP[apply(mat, 1, which.min)]`

Comment: @shouro In the [linked answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31668415/3526832) it is explained quite well I think.

Comment: Yes, misunderstood the code the first time...apologies.